# How to sum total div text

Tags: jquery, html

How to sum div text? I need comma xx,xxx for sum but the result with the script below is `7`

```js
var sum = 0;
$(".price").each(function () {
    var val = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (val) {
        val = parseInt(val.replace(/^\$/, ""));
        sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
    }
});
alert(sum);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">2,000</div>
<div class="price">1,000</div>
<div class="price">3,200</div>
<div class="price">1,000</div>
```

Comment: you're using parseInt, so the result is 7. That should get you thinking.

Comment: just do: `var sum = 0.0;`

Comment: sorry... did not see you used comma's.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `split` and `join` in javascript

```
var sum = 0;
$(".price").each(function() {
var val = parseInt($(this).text().split(",").join(""));
 sum = sum + val;
});

sum= sum.toString();
var lastThree = sum.substring(sum.length-3);
var otherNumbers = sum.substring(0,sum.length-3);
if(otherNumbers != '')
    lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;

alert(res);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwf4c077/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If more than 100000 -> 1,00,000

```
var sum = 0;
$(".price").each(function() {
var val = parseInt($(this).text().split(",").join(""));
 sum = sum + val;
});

sum= sum.toString();
var lastThree = sum.substring(sum.length-3);
var otherNumbers = sum.substring(0,sum.length-3);
if(otherNumbers != '')
    lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;

alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving a comma in there and parseInt doesn't like it.

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;
$(".price").each(function() {
var val = $.trim( $(this).text() );
if ( val ) {
val = parseInt( val.replace( /^\$/, "" ).replace(",","") );
sum += !isNaN( val ) ? val : 0;
}
});
alert(sum);
```